# Rails 4 ts_range not persisting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, range, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an issue with Rails 4's support for Postgresql's ts_range data type. Here is the code that I am trying to persist:

```
before_validation :set_appointment
attr_accessor :starting_tsrange, :ending_tsrange

def set_appointment
  self.appointment = convert_to_utc(starting_tsrange)...convert_to_utc(ending_tsrange)
end

def convert_to_utc
  ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("America/New_York").parse(time_string).utc
end
```

Basically I set an instance variable for the beginning and end of the appointment ts_range with two strings representing date_times. Before validation it converts them to utc and saves those values to the appointment attribute which should then be persisted. It sets things correctly but when I try to retrieve the record, the appointment attribute is now nil. Why is this code not working as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the subtle bug in the code. The issue here is with the triple dot range operator. If we get two values that are the exact same time. The triple dot will say include everything from time a up until time b if they are the same exact time, then nothing will be included and the result will be nil. This can be visualized with the code below

```
(1...1).to_a # []
(1..1).to_a # [1]
```

So the way to fix this is to not use the triple dot notation when using ranges that can have the same value for a time. Use the double dot notation instead.